# How to get PromiseValue with Promise {<pending>} Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Good afternoon. I'm new to working with Firebase batabase. Please tell me how to get data from my database to work with them farther.
Now my function returns Promise {} with the date that I need inside PromiseValue. How do I get it right. 
Now my code looks like this

```
let firebaseConfig = {
....
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let ref = firebase.database().ref('/data')

function getDataPromise() {
    return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val();
    });
  }
let res =  getDataPromise()
console.log(res)
```

I will be glad to any answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to get the data,like below

```
let firebaseConfig = { 
  ....
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let ref = firebase.database().ref('/data')

function getDataPromise() {
  return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
}

let res =  getDataPromise()
// Use then() with a callback to get data
res.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: how do i write this date to a variable?

Comment: You can't actually its asynchronous function.

Comment: see this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call